# Can I restart a program when I get an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm making a bot in discord.py, and I want to add a function that restarts the program if there is an error that would normally stop it. Specifically, something that restarts the bot when I get a TimeoutError. I've tried a couple different methods, including putting it in a `while` loop and using `os.execl()`, but the error still stops the program. Does anyone know if there's a way I can get this to work?

Comment: Give us a MVCE so we can better help

Comment: Maybe wrap your code in a `try` and `except` block and catch the `TimeoutError`.

Comment: @hqkhan I've tried that, but the error still gets through. I don't know why.

Comment: @IanQuah I don't know what a MVCE is. Mind explaining?

Comment: @IanQuah I understand now. Ill work on it.